# How to make the button just beside the bootstrap container

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap and have an issue making the button appear just beside the container at the center like what is shown in the picture. Oh ya, I know adding the button inside of the container can kind of partially solve this but I don't want to cause the button will take in some space in the container bootstrap grid.

[image: I want to move the button just next to container at the center]

Anyway to resolve this issue?

So far I try justify-content-center and text-right/text-left but to no avail.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="text-right my-auto" id="conveyorbelt-out">
    <button type="button" style="visibility: hidden;" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" id="conveyorbelt-leftbutton2"><b style="font-size:larger;"><</b></button>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="conveyorbelt-in">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Featured Products</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="conveyorbelt2 row overflow-auto flex-nowrap">
          <div class="card border-0" style="width: 10rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded lazyload" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <div class="card-text text-truncate text-center mt-auto mb-0 mb-0">MR BLECKY</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card border-0" style="width: 10rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded lazyload" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <div class="card-text text-truncate text-center mt-auto mb-0">PATIO</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card border-0" style="width: 10rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded lazyload" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <div class="card-text text-truncate text-center mt-auto mb-0">xCEL</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card border-0" style="width: 10rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded lazyload" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <div class="card-text text-truncate text-center mt-auto mb-0">Bagan</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card border-0" style="width: 10rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded lazyload" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <div class="card-text text-truncate text-center mt-auto mb-0">Boleh</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card border-0" style="width: 10rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded lazyload" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <div class="card-text text-truncate text-center mt-auto mb-0">PATIO</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card border-0" style="width: 10rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded lazyload" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <div class="card-text text-truncate text-center mt-auto mb-0">PATIO</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card border-0" style="width: 10rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded lazyload" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <div class="card-text text-truncate text-center mt-auto mb-0">PATIO</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card border-0" style="width: 10rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded lazyload" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <div class="card-text text-truncate text-center mt-auto mb-0">PATIO</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card border-0" style="width: 10rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded lazyload" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <div class="card-text text-truncate text-center mt-auto mb-0 text-center">PATIO</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card border-0" style="width: 10rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded lazyload" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <div class="card-text text-truncate text-center mt-auto mb-0">PATIO</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card border-0" style="width: 10rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded lazyload" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <div class="card-text text-truncate text-center mt-auto mb-0">PATIO</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card border-0" style="width: 10rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded lazyload" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <div class="card-text text-truncate text-center mt-auto mb-0 text-center">PATIO</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-auto" id="conveyorbelt-out">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" id="conveyorbelt-rightbutton2">></b></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please tag _only_ your Bootstrap version. You confuse us when you tag more than one.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the outermost 
  container
- Add align-items-center and justify-content-center  classes to the new
  container.
- This will vertically and horizontally center the content
  within the container.

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Your Rest Code-->
  </div>
  <div class="my-auto">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" id="conveyorbelt-rightbutton2">></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Container content here -->
  </div>
  <div class="my-auto">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" id="conveyorbelt-rightbutton2">></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried above code by just adding card elements in this section<!-- Container content here --> but I get something like this: https://imgur.com/a/0GLiHL4

Comment: Apolloid it work just remover justify-content from outermost  div